# How exactly do alcohol molecules dissolve in seawater?

Tags: molecules, alcohols

The book "Lehrbuch der anorganischen Chemie" by Arnold F. Hollemann on page 47[link here][1] states that dropping 0.8g Alcohol (M = 46g/mol) in a sea or ocean would result in every litre seawater containing 8 molecules alcohol.

This completely baffles me. How exactly does this happen?

[1]: https://books.google.de/bookshttps://books.google.de/books?id=eGkvSDAqY9gC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&ots=MFR61amS0x&focus=viewport&dq=ein mol alkohol in den weltmeeren&hl=de&output=html_text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my calculation.

The ocean has a volume of 1.3 billion cubic kilometers or 1.3e+18 cubic meters or 1.3e+21 liters. 0.8/46=0.0173 moles of ethyl alcohol x 6.02e+23 molecules per mole = 0.1047e+23 molecules, which if dissolved evenly in 1.3e+21 liters would give 10.47/1.3 or approx. 8 molecules of ethanol per liter.